# Why do I get the same number when using rand/srand in a function before main?

Tags: c++, random, srand

Why am I getting a different random number each time I run my code in main, but when I run it in a function I am getting a static number?

(1) Random number in Main...

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int loot = 1+(rand()%9);
    cout << loot;
    return 0;
}
```

(2) Random Number in a function outside of main...

```
using namespace std;

void lootTable(){
    srand(time(0));
    int loot = 1+(rand()%9);
    cout << loot;
}

int main()
{

    cout << lootTable;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Turn on/up your warnings.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7fdn4xvK8)

Comment: so declare it outside of main by itself?

Comment: Call srand at the start of main.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use srand/rand.

Comment: Look into [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). Nice example code on that page.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: Yes, chris's godbolt.org link above demonstrates that (as well as all the warnings that should be generated).

Comment: It seems like the OP hasn't mastered function calls yet. I think advice on improving their random number distribution may be premature.

Comment: They're comments and not answers.

Comment: @sweenish -- the problem here is not solved by using a different source of randomness. The problem is in seeding the RNG each time it's used.

Comment: @Pete Yes. But the use of srand()/rand() should also be discouraged.

Comment: @sweenish -- no, it shouldn't. Sometimes it's the right tool for the job. (Don't bother pointing me at Stephan Lavavej's stuff; I'm familiar with it) Having a shiny new tool doesn't mean it's always the right thing to use.

Comment: rand isn't ever the right tool in C++ anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right off the bat, you should know what the line `std::cout << lootTable;` does in your original code. It is equivalent to `std::cout << <address of lootTable function>;`, which is a non-zero value, which gets converted to a bool, which then results in printing `1`. When compiling, it is **highly** recommended to enable warnings, with at least `-Wall -Wextra`. You would have been warned about this issue right off the bat.

To call a function, you must always use the parameter list, `()`, even if it's empty.

`srand()` should only be called **once** in a program. It seeds your PRNG (Pseudo Random Number Generator), and we only seed a PRNG once. Easiest way is at the beginning of `main()`.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int lootTable() { return 1 + std::rand() % 9; }

int main() {
  std::srand(std::time(0));
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << lootTable() << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output of two separate runs:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
5 5 3 8 1 2 1 9 8 8 

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
6 5 5 7 8 7 5 6 8 4
```

Let's look at `looTable()`. I have used the signature from your attempt at answering your own question. Let's look at it piece by piece.

`int lootTable()`

This one's pretty straightforward. The first part, `int`, means that the function returns an integer. So your function must have at least one `return` statement. Your initial version had a `void` return type, meaning the function wouldn't return a value. That was likely not correct for your intended use.

Then, in your attempted answer, you got the return type fixed, but then failed to actually return anything, hence the downvotes.

The second part is the name, which you seem to have down, there were no issues calling the function.

The third part is the parameter list, which is empty in your case. Again, there doesn't appear to be an issue here.

---

What you should be doing instead of using `srand()`/`rand()` is utilizing `<random>`. It's randomness is less deterministic, and it separates the PRNG from the type of distribution that you want. The code below uses a [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), which means every value has an equal chance of appearing. For a loot table, you might prefer a [`std::normal_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) or [`std::lognormal_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/lognormal_distribution) or [whatever](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) floats your boat if you have different categories of loot.

Below is a short example program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int lootTable() {
  static std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> values(1, 9);

  return values(prng);
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << lootTable() << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output of two separate runs:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
2 6 7 8 2 1 8 7 8 5 

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
9 5 7 8 4 5 8 8 1 7
```

The `static` keyword allows the PRNG and distribution objects to persist between function calls. In other words, they won't be re-created every time the function is called. This allows them to behave optimally for the duration of your program.

**SLIGHT TANGENT:**
Seeding `std::mt19937` with a single 32-bit value is less than ideal, but it suffices for the purposes of a small program. Proper seeding would require enough extra work that wrapping `std::mt19937` with a class to ensure full seeding would be ideal. But given the contention that showing `<random>` was already too far off topic, I will not demonstrate any code. But here's a link if you're curious: https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/05/seeding-stdmt19937-random-number-engine.html

Comment: The stuff in `<random>` has exactly the same potential issue. Stick with your correct answer, since it answers the question.

Comment: It would be nice if you could also highlight OP's `lootTable` VS `lootTable()` issue, which is equally as much of an issue as the `srand`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Will add that.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't believe my implementation can suffer from the same issue.

Comment: @sweenish I will go ahead and dig into your response; im new to the whole coding thing so I will do my best to understand.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing. Note that I added a new paragraph at the beginning of my answer explaining a bit about how you need to call a function.

Comment: @sweenish -- you utterly miss the point. Yes, it's possible to write code using `<random>` that doesn't suffer from order-of-initializaiton problems. The same can be said for `rand/srand`. Merely changing from `rand()` to something in `<random>` won't fix design problems.

Answer (score -4):

Solved my issue, removed

```
cout << loot;
```

From the function.

```
using namespace std;

int lootTable(){
    int loot = 1+(rand()%9);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cout << lootTable();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. You need to `return loot;` in your `lootTable()` function.

Comment: If your compiler is not warning you about  these things you need to turn up the warning level. If it is try to understand the warnings. I expect any good compiler to warn about the issue that @FredLarson mentioned.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, it replaces it with a different problem. It's just a coincidence that it looks like it's working. `lootTable` has a non-void return type (its return type is `int`) so it must have a `return` statement which returns the function's result (`return loot;`).

Comment: So I need to return something when the function is an int? @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: Yes, you need a `return` statement which defines what the value of the function will be. You called it with `lootTable()` and you pass that function's return value to `cout` but you never defined that value in the function.